# Unable to decode gzip using cURL PHP

Tags: php, curl, gzip, deflate

I have been trying several ways, before deciding to ask this question here... no way has succeeded with me... I'm trying to decode and read the data from one site that use gzip.

I'm using cURL & PHP. When I try to decode and print the result, I'm getting a long list of garbled special characters such as:

```
 JHWkdsU01EUXdWa1pXYTFOdFZsZFRiaz
 VoVW14S2NGbFljRmRXYkdSWVpFZEdWRT
 FYVWtoWmEyaExXVlpLTm1KR1VsWmlXR2
```

If I run the below PHP script I got an error like:

```
 PHP Warning:  gzdecode(): data error in /var/www/mn.php on line 20
```

Here's my current code:

```
<?
$data_string = '9999';
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/getN.php&keyword=');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Darwin/15.0.0' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);


$result = gzdecode ( curl_exec($ch) );

curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);


?>
```

I also try to enable `deflate` module by:

```
  a2enmod deflate
  /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

and enable the `zlib` from `php.ini`

either I try to test it directly

```
curl -sH 'Accept-encoding: gzip' http://example.com/getN.php&keyword=9999 | gunzip -
```

I got the same result.

Here is the info from the site:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 15 Oct 2015 00:41:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.31
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

please help

Comment: its hard to debug this for you since the actual data from example.com does not appear to be gzipped

Answer (score 3):

I notice your code has

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
```

and a `gzdecode()` call later on. If instructed to accept encoded content, cURL handles decoding automatically for you, without the need to manually do it after `curl_exec()`. Its return value is already decoded if you told cURL to accept encoded transfer.

That said, the page you are trying to download may not be actually be encoded with gzip, but another method. As stated in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php), try specifying an empty string:

```
# Enable all supported encoding types.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
```

This enables all supported encoding types. And don't use `gzdecode()`. The result should be already decoded.

Comment: I tried that with/without 
(gzip, gzdecode, Accept-Encoding: gzip/deflate) all are give me the same result 
(long list of garbled special characters) or error (PHP Warning:  gzdecode(): data error in line number)
I also copy the gzip code and try to decode it manually either that not working ...
bwt .. I've this [link](https://www.samltool.com/gzip.php)  website they decode my gzip code online without any issue ..working !!
so that confirm me this issue either in my code or in the server setting. 
(my server NOT decode ).

Comment: You shouldn't have to set the Content-Length yourself. If you use cURL to send an HTTP POST, it will calculate the content length for you, and automatically add the required Content-Length header. It might be smaller than `strlen($data_string)` if cURL compresses the content. Also, remove CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER entirely, and add a CURLOPT_POST option set to true.

Answer (score 0):

thanks all  ,,  finally start working after I take your advice and remove gzdecode and some others and keep the header to.. Accept Encoding to gzip and here the final code

```
<?
$data_string = '9999';
$ch = curl_init('http://example.com/getN.php&keyword=');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Darwin/15.0.0' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // Follow redirects
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
);


$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
print $result;


?>
```